# How to schedule Background Task with FastAPI + Uvicorn + Celery in Production for lower response time?

Tags: python, machine-learning, celery, fastapi, uvicorn

I am running FastAPI + Uvicorn server setup on EC2 instance. I am using 4 Uvicorn workers and 4 celery workers on 8vCPU Ec2 instance. I am performing very simple task. I get data on post API, schedule background task using celery and return response immediately. For this simple task if I send 40 concurrent request at sec, I get p99 as 600 ms which is very high. It should be within two digit. What could be going wrong? BackgroundTasks which is built-in for FastAPI wont be of any help here because I have cpu bound task which takes time to execute. I have already tried it.

```python
from fastapi import FastAPI
from celeryy import Celery

celery_app = Celery("tasks", broker="redis://localhost:6379/0", backend="redis://localhost:6379/0")

app = FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan)

def generate_model_score(request_data):
   # Calculate ML model score
   pass

@app.post("/predict/")
async def sample_fn(request_data: dict):
    
    if total_transactions == 0:
        logger.info("user doesnt have any data")
        return default_response(request_data['userId'])
    
    generate_model_score.delay(request_data)
    logger.debug("end of predict")

    # Respond with dummy data immediately
    return default_response(request_data['userId'])
```

Comment: Increase the worker counts use this formula to get worker count `(2 x $num_cores) + 1`

Comment: That will obviously improve response time. However, I am not doing anything heavy in API . With 4 workers response time should be very less for few concurrent request.

Comment: Check your ec2 [type](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/) based on that you can check ***Network Bandwidth** also check your region.